# how can i toggle more than three images in listview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview with an image on each row now what i want is i want to change that image onclick,now if it were two images it would have been quite simple.i could have used boolean and set the position of item's image to be changed.
but my case involves more than two images
On 1st click image changes to image0
On 2nd click image changes to image1
On 3rd click image changes to image2
and On 4th click image changes back to image
And images are toggling pretty fine but once when the list is reloaded everything changes as the toggled image position changes from 0 to 8 and so on.I have tried setting default behaviour too.
So,here is my sample code

```
     @Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;


    if(convertView==null){ 

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.image.setTag(position);

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/

        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        Log.i("Mainly at", Integer.toString(position)+"state is "+tempValues.getStatus());
        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
         holder.text1.setText(tempValues.getUrl());


            // holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);
         if(tempValues.getStatus().equals(ListModel.imageStateNone))
         {
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);
         }

         if(tempValues.getStatus().equals(ListModel.imageStateAnotherCase))
         {


         if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==0){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);// or what it should be in default
        }


         if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==1){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);// or what it should be in default
        }

         if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==2){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);// or what it should be in default
        }


         }


         /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
 //        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }
    return vi;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
    tempValues.setStateAsChange();
       Log.e("clicked at", Integer.toString(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos())+"Changed state is "+tempValues.getStatus()+"And position"+Integer.toString(position));
       tempValues.setImageStateAtPos(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()+1);

       if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()>2){
           tempValues.setImageStateAtPos(0);
       }
   //    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
        holder.image = (ImageView)rl.getChildAt(0);
     //   ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==0){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);// or what it should be in default
        }


         if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==1){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);// or what it should be in default
        }

         if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==2){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);// or what it should 
        }
         if(tempValues.getImageStateAtPos()==3){
             holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image10);
        }



}


 }
```

ListModel code is here
    private String status="";

```
  public static final String imageStateNone="none"; 
  public static final String imageStateAnotherCase="changed"; 
 private int state;
/****
     HashMap<Integer, String> set=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  public void setStateAsnone(int pos)
    {
set.put(pos,imageStateNone );
 }


  public void setStateAsChange(int pos)
{
set.put(pos, imageStateAnotherCase);
//this.status = imageStateAnotherCase;
   }

 public String getStatus(int pos)
  {
return set.get(pos);
  }



 public void setImageStateAtPos(int state){
this.state=state;
 }

 public int getImageStateAtPos(){
return state;
 }





public void setStateAsnone()
{
    this.status = imageStateNone;
}


public void setStateAsChange()
{
    this.status = imageStateAnotherCase;
}

public String getStatus()
{
    return status;
}
```

and finally adding data in mainactivity

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

          /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
           sched.setCompanyName("Company "+i);
           sched.setImage("image"+i);
           sched.setUrl("http:\\\\www."+i+".com");
           sched.setImageStateAtPos(0);
           sched.setStateAsnone();
        /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
    }

enter code here
```

Everything works like charm until the list reloads everything gets messed up when list reloads tried using status position indicator using hashmap.Just want to know now that how can i stop changing position of toggling of image when listview is reloaded.
Help out.

Comment: check the answer i just posted, hope it helps

Comment: @HassaanRabbani no need for such a comment. He will get a notification for each new post, so no need to make a "take a look" comment to get him notificated twice...

Answer (score 1):

Put a data in your ListModel object that represent whether the row item bound to it changed or not. then  add this statement to your `getView()`  something like this:

```
getView(){

    if(model.getImageSate()==ImageState.NONE){
         holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);// or what it should be in default
    }
    if(model.getImageSate()==ImageState.YetAnotherState){,
          holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.theOtherImage);
    }
...
}
```

**EDIT**

I assume that you are using a custom Object for yoour ListItems. so here

```
    class ListModel{

    // you may use a String variable or an enumeration for this. ill use a
    string field for this example: 

     public static final String imageStateNone="none"; 
     public static final String imageStateAnotherCase="anothercase"; 
     private String imageState;

     //getter - setter for imageState field

     }
```

in case you are using a predefined class from sdk or other library.
inherit it and put your variables like this:

```
class ExtendedObject extends ListModel{


     public static final String imageStateNone="none"; 
     public static final String imageStateAnotherCase="anothercase"; 
     private String imageState;

     //getter - setter for imageState field



}
```

don't forget to use string.equals("") for comparing strings.

Comment: can you just give a hint on how imagestate can be made in model and how will it work on both onclick and getview?

Comment: i am able to toggle images but gets worse when list reloads clicks at item1 changes at item 8,9 and so on.

Comment: the common pit fall:  use a default like i mentioned at my answer. and set the image at this default case to null or whatever it should be. you know the list view recyles the views and some views return to you setted with another image before it recycled

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This is quite simple and orthodox way of doing it.

Create an integer variable. and initialize it with 0.

```
Public int flag = 0;

If(flag==0)
{
    // change to image 2
       flag=flag+1;
} else if (flag==1)
{
    // change to image 3
       flag=flag+1;
} else if (flag==2)
{
    // change to image 4
       flag=0;
}
```

Comment: How will it work for all the items in the listview,and i want to change image on click.So,how will it work?

Comment: you can add this code in your onClick method, and change respective image. if fist click then flag=1 and change that image if second click then flag=2 and so on

Comment: but problem when list reloads still persists

Comment: make the flag static. and then check. by making it static you will actually saving the state of flag in all occurrences

Comment: are you saving the state of the list view by any means?